# Datalog with negation in Z3

Tags: z3

I'm trying to write this Datalog program in Z3:

```
p :- r.
q :- \r.
```

As per [this tutorial](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/fixedpoints), I wrote:

```
(declare-rel p ())
(declare-rel q ())
(declare-rel r ())
(rule (=> r p))
(rule (=> (not r) q))

(set-option :fixedpoint.engine datalog)

(rule r)
(query p :print-answer true)
```

Now, I'd like to replace `(rule r)` by `(rule (not r))`, to deduce `q`, but I get:

> (error "query failed: Illegal head. The head predicate needs to be
>   uninterpreted and registered (as recursive) (not r)")

Answer (score 3):

`r` is assumed to be false by default, so you don't need to say `(rule (not r))`.

`(query q :print-answer true)` will yield `true`.